# How to share global variables between two executables?

Tags: c++, compilation, global-variables

So let's say I have two files, `main1.cc` and `main2.cc`, each with a main function and each with a set of global variables defined in their respective files:

**main1.cc**:

```
int main1_global = 1;

int main() {
  // I am main 1
}
```

**main1_globals.h**:

```
extern int main1_global;
```

**main2.cc**:

```
#include "main1_globals.h"

int main2_global = 2;
int main() {
  // I am main 2
}
```

The issue is that main2.cc uses main1_global and if I try to link and compile main2, then it complains that there are multiple definitions of main.

Ideally I should not be linking main1 to main2, but I want main2 to include the globals from main1. What's the best way to link the globals from main1 into main2 without linking main1 ?

Comment: But you do have multiple definitions of `main`. That's not allowed.

Comment: Edited my post because it wasn't clear. I know there's two definitions of main, just wondering what the best way to include main1's global into main2 without linking main1.

Comment: i do not understand. What exactly does "share" mean? Should modification of `main1_global` in executable1 be visible in executable2? (I wonder, if it would be possible to modify linker to place global variables in shared memory...)

Comment: Oh, so you wrote 2 `main`s because you are trying to solve the "sharing global variables" problem? If so, the question is misleading; it reads like you already had 2 `main`s for some other reason.

Comment: I guess what I want is not sharing, but really just trying to import globals from one place without running into linking issues.

Comment: What do you mean by "import"? What are these globals used for? Why not just write `int main1_globa = 1` in `main2.cc` and forget about it? Possibly do you ask how to share the same code between two programs?

Comment: In a few words: don't share global variables between different executables.

Answer (score 2):

Put your constants in a separate file, for example globals.h. Then include this file in both your executables.

Comment: do you intialise and define the globals in globals.h ?

Comment: What would that file look like if both .c modules will include it?

Answer (score 1):

> How to share global variables between two executables?

On most [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), each [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (obtained by compilation then linking of C++ files) is running in its own [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), and each process has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Read some good [Operating Systems textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) for more.

In practice, **you cannot easily share global variables, and when you could, there is a synchronization issue** (what would happen on a [multi-core processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_core) with one core running executable 1 and another running executable 2 at the same time?).

You probably want some [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). When possible, sharing a global variable could be expensive in CPU time.

If on Linux, see [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [socket(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [shm_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), [sem_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)

For Windows, study the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/)

You could redesign the architecture of your software to use multi-threading, e.g. C++ [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)-s, but then you'll probably need also [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) for locking purposes and [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)-s for synchronizations.

Be aware of the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) and [cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) issues. Even when you do share a global variable, you could have performance issues.

You might redesign your application to use a [message-passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) paradigm, e.g. with [JSONRPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org/) or [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) or [ONCRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call). Of course, sending a message is costly (but is the base of [cloud computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) in [data centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_center)). It could take milliseconds, not nanoseconds.